# Populating a dataframe from a key value pair from dictionary

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I make 2 lists and 2 dictionaries, where keys are elements of the list and values are supposed to change.

```
n = 1
mras = '2'+str(n)+'_'+str(day)+str(month)+str(year[-2:])
hanim='1'+str(n)+'_'+str(day)+str(month)+str(year[-2:])
mras_list = []
hanim_list = []
mras_list.append(mras)
hanim_list.append(hanim)
mras_dict =  { fruit : "" for fruit in mras_list }
keys = list(mras_dict.keys())

hanim_dict =  { fruit : "" for fruit in hanim_list }
hanim_keys = list(hanim_dict.keys())

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns =['Elena', 'Состояние', 'Oleg', 'Состоянie'] )
df = df.reindex(df.index.tolist() + list(range(1, 40)))
```

I then want to populate the dataframe with dictionary's pairs (dataframe already exists):

```
for h in emails: 
    for u in mras_list:
        for j in mras_dict:
            for p in hanim_dict:
                if h in mras_list: 
                    mras_dict[u] = "Запрос направлен"
                    df['Oleg'][n], df['Состоянie'][n] = j, [j] in mras_dict.items()
                if h in hanim_dict:
                    hanim_dict[p] = "Запрос направлен"
```

j, [j] makes mistakes. Could you please advise, how to get the pair of a dictionary and populate with it 2 columns of a dataframe? With "df['Oleg'][n], df['Состоянie'][n] = j, [j] in mras_dict.items()" I wish to say to the PC "take key and value and put them to those columns. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for k, v in hanim_dict.items():
  df['Elena'][n], df['Состояние'][n] = k, v
```

Yesterday my head could not find that out